# Path to the exe or dll that contains the metadata resources

Tags: windows, path, message, executable

[Microsoft's help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/identifying-the-provider) says to put "path to the exe or dll that contains the metadata resources" and "path to the exe or dll that contains the string resources" into the `.man` XML file defining application's messages.

Should the path be the absolute path after installation? Can I use a relative path? If yes, relative to which directory?